# Find the username of a windows machine from a raspberry pi

Tags: javascript, php, python

Is there a way to get the username of a windows machine, remotely from a raspberry pi?

We have created a bespoke program on a few raspberry pi's and need to know what user is accessing these pi's remotely when running the program. This is to tailor the experience to the windows user dependent on their windows login.

We have used the .get_current_user on the pi, but it returns the username of the pi not the windows machine.

Comment: I believe there is... Let me check. What are you using, Python?

Comment: what do you mean by `"username of a machine"`?

Comment: also, how is the program accessed remotely? Via SSH?

Comment: Have you already defined environmental variables on each machine, such as `export MACHINE_NAME="MACHINE01"`?  If so you can get that info quite easily in any scripting language.

Comment: If you want to know the name of user agent machine then it is not possible.

Comment: when the user logs in to the windows machine with standard windows username and password, can the pi find the username they have used to login across a LAN network?

Comment: @SpencerAustin you can get the computer's name via lan, not the username currently logged in.